# Remove array elements belonging to the same group leaving only 1 of the group?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array `myArray[]` of objects `MyThing` which contains X elements. I need to remove elements belonging to the same group, but leaving one representative of each group.

`MyThing` class has a field `groupId`

```
public class MyThing {

  private int groupId;
  //...other fields

  public int getGroupId(){return groupId;}
  //getter and setter
}
```

So I have to compare `groupId` integer value of array elements (`myArray[x].getGroupId()`) and **remove all element belonging the same group except the first such element in the array**.

This way I will get an array of unique elements with only 1 from the same group. For example, if I have an array with `a.getGroupId()=1, b.getGroupId()=2, c.getGroupId()=1` after purification, the array will contain only `{a,b}`, and `c` will be removed since it's of the same group as `a`.

Because this is the custom object, I cannot use `Set<T>`.

Any ideas?

PS. please let me know if I explained this clearly since it's kind of confusing.

Comment: You can still use a set which stores only the group IDs and use that to eliminate the duplicates

Comment: You can use a Map with Key being your GroupId and Value being first array element in that group. Then simple checks on Map keys can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set by definition doesn't contain any duplicates. A set determines if two items are alike, by using either the objects equals()/compareTo(..) method or by using a Comparator. If you only want unique items in your set, implementing the Comparable interface and overriding equals() is what you want to do. BUT in your case, you're only interested in objects in unique groups, so it's then better to create a custom Comparator for the occasion, which you then supply to the Set, telling it to use it, instead of "natural ordering".

```
Set<MyThing> myThings = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<MyThing>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyThing  o1, MyThing  o2)
        {
            return o1.getGroupId() - o2.getGroupId(); 
        }
    }); 
myThings.addAll(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

After creating the set, you add your entire array into it, using the convinience method addAll(..).

(How the comparator sorts your objects is completely up to you to decide.)

Comment: OMG this works. Even quicker than James' solution. Can you edit the reply and explain the logic here. I've never used `TreeSet` and `Comparator` before.

Comment: @sandalone TreeSet is a built in collection that relies on order. Since the normal Set interface only cares about equality and not order, the TreeSet takes a `Comparator` as a constructor argument which it uses instead of `equals()`/`hashcode()` during insertion.

Comment: I got that already. The same as using `LinkedHasSet<T>` to keep order. I was confused by overridden method `compare` which created 2 objects of `MyThing` and subtracted values of its fields (group id in my case). Why? What was the purpose of this?

Comment: It uses the method you supply ( compare(MyThing a, MyThing b) ) to determine the order/alikeness of objects added to it. The method you supply must return 0 when to objects are determined "equal".

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TreeSet` and a custom `Comparator` class that inspects your objects and treats two with the same group as equal.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Algorithm psuedocode:

```
Create TreeSet
Add all array elements to TreeSet
Convert TreeSet back to array
```

For a sample implementation: [see Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23093565/1311351)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through your array and use a map to keep track of which IDs have already occurred.  Then if one was already added to the set, remove it from the array:

```
Set<Integer> uniqueIDs = new HashSet<Integer>();

for(MyThing thing : MyThings){
    int groupID = thing.getGroupId();

    if(!uniqueIDs.add(groupID)){
        // DUPLICATE, REMOVE IT
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Check @Martin's solution. So elegant and quick.

Comment: @sandalone Just note that TreeSet is ordered.  Not sure if the overall order of your list is important.

Comment: Yes, order is important here.

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrote the Martin's solution because the comparator is broken, it might overflow

```
Set<MyThing> myThings = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<MyThing>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(MyThing  o1, MyThing  o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o1.getGroupId(), o2.getGroupId()); 
  }
}); 
myThings.addAll(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like (semi-pseudo-code here):

```
List<Integer> uniqGroups = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    int groupId = myArray[i].getGroupId();

    if (!uniqGroups.contains(groupId)) {
        // Hasn't been seen before, keep around
        uniqGroups.add(groupId);
    }
    else {
        // Already seen, remove or otherwise clean up the array
        myArray[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `Set<T>` as `LinkedHashSet<T>` can do all this in 1 line ;)

Comment: `Set<Integer> obj = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myArray));`. With this you will even preserve an order of items if it's important like in my case.

Answer (score -1):

As you just need to distinguish your objects by groupId, you might override the **hashCode()** and **equals()** methods in your class:

```
class MyThing {
    private int groupId;
    public int getGroupId(){return groupId;}

    // new code to add...
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return groupId;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof MyThing
             && (groupId == ((MyThing)o).groupId));
    }
}
```

and then, use a **HashSet<MyThing>** class to remove the MyThing objects in myArray with duplicated groupId:

```
myArray = new HashSet<MyThing>(Arrays.asList(myArray)).toArray(new MyThing[0]);
```